# Views in container doesn't show with the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a DrawerLayout here that works perfeclty on API 21 and higher but when I am on KitKat and lower versions, the "buttonMenu" doesn't show.
"buttonMenu" allows the user to open and close the drawer.

Thank you for your help.

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Map">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMenu"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_black_48dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#48BF57"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
</FrameLayout>


<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="com.app.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I would imagine it's getting hidden behind whatever content you add to the `FrameLayout`. You might consider using an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` instead, since it's meant for exactly that function. Otherwise, you can try calling `bringToFront()` on your `Button` each time after adding/replacing the content in the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Mike, you could also change the fragment height to 0dp or something small to see if you can see the button render.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've already thought about this but I don't want to use the whole bar. Indeed I checked what @Krum110487 has said and my button is behind another layout (in this case, a map). I'm lost... I have no way to get the "buttonMenu" view after having inflated the map